# How can I set an address to be a relative offset pointer in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

I have the following sequence of bytes in IDA Pro:

```
.text:0044A838          db 2Ah
.text:0044A839          db 0ADh ; ­
.text:0044A83A          db    4
.text:0044A83B          db    0
.text:0044A83C          dd rva word_44AD3E     
.text:0044A840          dd rva word_44AD4C
.text:0044A844          dd rva word_44AD5C
```

This region *should* be interpreted as four consecutive relative pointers, but right now, it is four raw bytes, and then three relative pointers. How can I instruct IDA that the first element is a relative offset pointer?

When I mark the first element as being a 32-bit integer, the its simply the value 0x4AD2A, which IDA does not recognize as being an xref that I can follow. I cannot mark this 32-bit element as an offset (by pressing `O`), since the address 0x4AD2A is not valid in this executable.

Answer (score 2):

Define the element to be the appropriate size (such as by pressing `d` repeatedly). Then press `Ctrl-R` (or use the menu entry: `Edit->Operand Type->Offset->Offset (User Defined)`), select `Use image base as offset base`, and accept the dialog.

[image: example diallog]

Comment: And if the resulting address is above 4G, make sure to choose OFF64, even if it is a 32-bit variable. The width of the memory cell need not match the size of the resulting address.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>U</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> or you may be able to get away with <kbd>U</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

Note: the leading <kbd>U</kbd> is to ensure you are starting from a consistent state, and is not strictly necessary.

Key meanings:

<kbd>U</kbd> - Undefine
<kbd>D</kbd> - Data [byte]
<kbd>D</kbd> - Data [word]
<kbd>D</kbd> - Data [dword]
<kbd>O</kbd> - Offset

or

<kbd>U</kbd> - Undefine
<kbd>Q</kbd> - Hex (will convert to D/QWORD for free)
<kbd>O</kbd> - Offset

*I (heart) Vim*

Comment: using O/Offset usually interprets the data as a VA rather than RVA, which is what I am looking for here.

Comment: When-ever I do this in my own code, (64 bit, __ImageBase at 0x140000000 and QWORD values), they come out perfectly as (Absolute) values.   If you are doing 32 bit stuff, I am officially clueless, and the only relative offsets in the 64 bit work I do are the RIP relative type.    However, I did notice the other day while browsing the configuration options of IDA that there's a tremendous list of things you can assign to keyboard shortcuts -- so you might be able to figure something.   Otherwise, I could write a quick Python based hotkey for you if I understood your crazy 32bit world.